# Can you use a stringstream to safely convert bidirectionally?

Tags: c++, formatting, stringstream

I have this case where a double is converted to a string using a stringstream. Now, I have to get back that value somewhere else (no, I have no access to the original double), so I have to parse the formatted string.

Ofcourse, I can read it just with a stringstream as well, but is that safe? Will it always work, for all values?

```
std::ostringstream doubleToString;
double myDouble = 3.14;
doubleToString << myDouble;
std::string convertedDouble = doubleToString.str();

std::istringstream stringToDouble(convertedDouble);
double newDouble;
stringToDouble >> newDouble;
```

In the example above, will myDouble always be equal to newDouble?

Note: marginal differences (0.00000000001) are not my concern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it will not always work.  You can prove this to yourself using this minor modification of your code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream doubleToString;
    double zero = 0;
    double myDouble = 3.14/zero;
    doubleToString << myDouble;
    std::string convertedDouble = doubleToString.str();
    std::cout << "convertedDouble = " << convertedDouble << std::endl;

    std::istringstream stringToDouble(convertedDouble);
    double newDouble;
    stringToDouble >> newDouble;
    std::cout << "newDouble = " << newDouble << std::endl;
    assert(newDouble == myDouble);
}
```

When I run this code on my machine, I get this output:

```
convertedDouble = inf
newDouble = 0
xlat: xlat.cpp:19: int main(): Assertion `newDouble == myDouble' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

## Update:

Note that if you always start with a double in the range of representable floating point numbers on your particular machine (that is `std::numeric_limits<double>::min() <= x <= std::numeric_limits<double>::max()`) it still isn't guaranteed.  As an example of this try the code above with `double myDouble = 1/3.0;`.  The issue is one of precision when emitting the `double` to a string.  We can try to address that by modifying the code to use this:

```
doubleToString << 
    std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10) << myDouble;
```

This has the effect of setting the precision to as many decimal digits as are needed for an integer value that will *always* survive transformation into and back from a `double`.  However, it still won't work for all double values!

```
double myDouble = pow(1/3.0, 300);
```

This value will cause the assert to trigger.  The reason is that the `digits10` is *only* for the mantissa portion of the floating point number and doesn't represent the exponent.  Getting completely pedantic here, we can set the right value as:

```
constexpr int dblprecision = std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 
        + ceil(log10(std::numeric_limits<double>::max_exponent10));
doubleToString << std::setprecision(dblprecision) << myDouble;
```

Note that this is only needed in the double-to-string conversion direction and not the other way.

So with the understanding that the input value must be in the indicated range, and provided you set the precision for the conversion to string, I *think* this will always result in the original double, assuming no bugs in the implementation of the compiler or library.

Comment: Very good example! In my case, I can rely on the fact that I start with valid doubles. Nothing funky like inf :). So, with that in mind, is it still unsafe?

Comment: @W.Goeman: I've addressed that question in an update to the answer.

Comment: Perfect. That's all I had to know. Thanks a lot